# Problem with generic traits and lifetimes

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime

I had a problem with generic traits in a larger context and try to size it down to this smaller problem. I want to have following function:

```
fn count<I, S, T>(pattern: T, item:I) -> usize
where
  I: Atom,
  S: Iterator<Item = I> 
  T: Atoms<I, S>,
{
  pattern.atoms().filter(|i| i == &item).count()
}
```

The function should be passed two arguments:

- `pattern:Atoms<...>` which has a factory method atoms returning an iterator of atoms
- `item:Atom` which is the item that should be counted in the iterator of atoms

The function should be generic over both arguments (with the constraint that `pattern.atoms()` must return an iterator with items of the same type as `item`), e.g.:

```
count(Atoms<u8, std::str::Bytes<'_>>, u8) -> usize
count(Atoms<char, std::str::Chars<'_>>, char) -> usize
count(Atoms<u8, std::io::Bytes>, u8) -> usize
```

For Atom I tried this approach:

```
pub trait Atom: Copy + Eq + Ord + Display + Debug {}
impl Atom for char {}
impl Atom for u8 {}
```

Next I started with Atoms, first without lifetimes:

```
pub trait Atoms<I, S>
where
  S: Iterator<Item = I>,
  I: Atom,
{
  fn atoms(&self) -> S;
}
```

I tried to implement this for `str` using `std::str::Bytes<'a>` as iterator. Consequently the compiler misses a lifetime annotation `&'a self` in atoms. So I refined this approach with lifetimes and came up with this code:

```
pub trait Atoms<'a, I, S>
where
  S: Iterator<Item = I> + 'a,
  I: Atom,
{
  fn atoms(&'a self) -> S;
}

impl<'a> Atoms<'a, u8, std::str::Bytes<'a>> for &str {
  fn atoms(&'a self) -> std::str::Bytes<'a> {
    self.bytes()
  }
}

fn count<'a, I, S, T>(pattern: T, item: I) -> usize
where
  I: Atom,
  S: Iterator<Item = I> + 'a,
  T: Atoms<'a, I, S>,
{
  pattern.atoms().filter(|i| *i == item).count() //<--- compiler complains 
}
```

[Playground-Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=868a50ff96ef0851c7dabb3b74832f47)

Now the compiler complains `the parameter type` T `may not live long enough, ... consider adding ... T:'a`. I do not understand this problem. The hint does not even work (another lifetime problem follows) so I have no clue what my misunderstanding is. Can someone help me to understand (or even fix) this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `atoms` function requires `self` to be borrowed for a lifetime of `'a`. If you give to this function a type that does not live that long, this function cannot work properly.

For example, the type `&'b T` has a lifetime of `'b`. If you implement `Atoms` for `&'b T` and that `'b` is shorter that `'a`, you must not be able to call the `atoms` function. This is why you must constrain `T` to live at least as long as `'a`.

Rust knows this and automatically do this to the `atoms` function:

```rust
fn atoms(&'a self) -> std::str::Chars<'a>
where
    Self: 'a,
{ self.chars() }
```

But when you try to use that function inside of another function, Rust needs you to add this bond yourself. This is why you need to add it for the `count` function.

### The second problem

Your `Atom` trait does not need to carry the `'a` lifetime. Your first approach was the right one.

```rust
pub trait Atoms<S>
where
  S: Iterator,
  S::Item: Atom,
{
  fn atoms(&self) -> S;
}
```

*(note that I removed the generic parameter `I` and replaced it with `S::Item`. This is possible because `Item` is an associated type of `Iterator`. That changes nothing apart from being clearer.)*

After that, the implementations are pretty straightforward.

```rust
// Note the `&'a str` here, this was missing on your implementation but it is actually
// needed. If you think about it, the bytes that are returned are part of the `&str`
// so they must live at least as long as the reference.
impl<'a> Atoms<std::str::Bytes<'a>> for &'a str {
    // The difference is here. You don't need to chose a lifetime for `&self`.
    // A longer lifetime than `'a` would be ok. That would be a reference to
    // a reference of a lifetime of `'a`.
    //
    // `self` is `&'a str` here.
    // so `&self` is `&&'a str`
    //
    // What you did was telling Rust that that second reference needed to live
    // as long as `'a`. Meaning `&'a &'a str`. But this was wrong. That reference
    // must be able to live longer than `'a`.
    fn atoms(&self) -> std::str::Bytes<'a> {
        self.bytes()
    }
}
```

After that, the `count` function work just as intended:

```rust
fn count<S, T>(pattern: T, item: I) -> usize
where
  S::Item: Atom,
  S: Iterator,
  T: Atoms<S>,
{
  pattern.atoms().filter(|i| *i == item).count() //<--- compiler does not complain anymore ;)
}
```

Comment: The second hint solved the problem. Many thanks. I was aware of the lifetime issue you mentioned first, but then puzzled after adding `T:'a`, which caused another problem (`'pattern' does not live long enough`). Do you have an explantion for that (should be reproducable in the playground).

Comment: I think it has to do with `count` owning `pattern` which causes it to be dropped when it returns (before the end of `'a`) but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: A note on transforming `I:Atom` to `S::Item`: You mentioned, that it changes nothing apart from being clearer. And actually definition compiles afterwards. But using the definition like `count("ababbc", 'a')` results in `type `S` cannot be inferred` (test it in the playground). So it seems that the compiler can infer more information from the original type signature.