# Lifetimes for generalizing trait implementation from &T to AsRef<T>

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I have some problems generalizing a trait working for `&str` to other string types (e.g. `Rc<str>`, `Box<str>`,`String`).

First of all my example function should work for:

```
assert_eq!(count("ababbc", 'a'), 2);                // already working
assert_eq!(count(Rc::from("ababbc"), 'a'), 2);      // todo
assert_eq!(count("ababbc".to_string(), 'a'), 2);    // todo
```

This is the working code, which makes the first test run:

```
pub trait Atom: Copy + Eq + Ord + Display + Debug {}
impl Atom for char {}

pub trait Atoms<A, I>
where
  I: Iterator<Item = A>,
  A: Atom,
{
  fn atoms(&self) -> I;
}

impl<'a> Atoms<char, std::str::Chars<'a>> for &'a str {
  fn atoms(&self) -> std::str::Chars<'a> {
    self.chars()
  }
}

pub fn count<I, A, T>(pattern: T, item: A) -> usize
where
  A: Atom,
  I: Iterator<Item = A>,
  T: Atoms<A, I>,
{
  pattern.atoms().filter(|i| *i == item).count()
}
```

To make the next tests run, I changed the signature of `count` and `Atoms` in following way:

```
pub trait Atoms<'a, A, I>
where
  I: Iterator<Item = A> + 'a,
  A: Atom,
{
  fn atoms<'b>(&'b self) -> I
  where
    'b: 'a;
}

impl<'a, S> Atoms<'a, char, std::str::Chars<'a>> for S
where
  S: AsRef<str> + 'a,
{
  fn atoms<'b>(&'b self) -> std::str::Chars<'b>
  where
    'b: 'a,
  {
    self.as_ref().chars()
  }
}
```

but now the function count does not compile any more:

```
pub fn count<'a, I, A, T>(pattern: T, item: A) -> usize
where
  A: Atom,
  I: Iterator<Item = A> + 'a,
  T: Atoms<'a, A, I>,
{
  pattern.atoms().filter(|i| *i == item).count()
}
```

[Playground-Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d3022b92a99c5fd555abd0dbfbc09cc1)

The compiler error is: `the parameter type 'T' may not live long enough ... consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: 'T: 'a'`. This is not completely understandable for me, so I tried to apply the help `T: Atoms<'a, A, I> + 'a`. Now the error is: `'pattern' does not live long enough ... 'pattern' dropped here while still borrowed`.

Since the latter error also occurs without implementations of `Atoms` and by just replacing the function body by `pattern.atoms();return 1;` I suspect that the type signature of `Atoms` is not suitable for my purpose.

Has anybody a hint what could be wrong with the type signature of `Atoms` or `count`?

Comment: Are there more examples? Your current examples could be satisfied by just having `count` be `fn count<S: AsRef<str>>(pattern: S, item: char) -> usize`

Comment: `Atoms` is an abstraction for a source of `u8` or `char` iterators. So Atoms will also be implemented for `std::str::Bytes` as well as `std::io::Bytes` and more sources of chars and bytes. So `count` will be generic in both two arguments (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65618771/problem-with-generic-traits-and-lifetimes)).

Comment: This [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734640/how-do-i-specify-lifetime-parameters-in-an-associated-type) is similar, but with associated types.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
trait Atoms<'a, A, I> where I: Iterator<Item = A> + 'a ...
```

By writing this, you're requiring the iterator to **outlive** the lifetime `'a`. Since `'a` is part of the trait's generic parameters, it must be a lifetime that extends before you start using (implicitly) `<String as Atoms<'a, char, std::str::Chars>>::atoms`. This directly contradicts the idea of returning a new iterator object, since that object did *not* exist before the call to `atoms()`.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to rewrite this so that it will work, without generic associated types (a feature not yet stabilized), but I hope that at least this explanation of the problem helps.

Comment: The constrait `I: Iterator<Item = A> + 'a` was added with the intention to limit the lifetime's upper bound, yet I agree with your interpretation. So I removed this constraint, but the problem stays.

Comment: You mention a contradiction to `<String as Atoms<'a, char, std::str::Chars>>::atoms`. I assume this is an example and should stand for: for all T that are owned types `<T as Atoms<'a, char, std::str::Chars>>::atoms` will be a contradition? Because the compiler shows up the error even if the trait has no implementation (especially not for string).

Comment: Can you give an impression how it would look like with generic associated types?

Comment: @CoronA I'm afraid I haven't explored that part of Rust myself and don't have any good further explanation to give you. I only thought that a partial answer would be more helpful than no answer.

Comment: Yes it was helpful, thank you. Maybe another reader can get into these details.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I clarify at least some parts of the problem. After doing some internet research on HRTBs and GATs I come to the conclusion that my problem is hardly solvable with stable rust.

The main problem is that one cannot

- have a trait with different lifetime signature than its implementations
- keep lifetimes generic in a trait for later instantiation in the implementation
- limit the upper bound of a results lifetime if it is owned

I tried several approaches to but most evolve to fail:

- at compiling the implementation (because the implementations lifetimes conflict with those of the trait)
- at compiling the caller of the trait because a compiling implementation limits the lifetimes in a way, that no object can satisfy them.

At last I found two solutions:

### Implement the trait for references

- the function `atoms(self)` does now expect `Self` and not `&Self`
- `Atoms<A,I>` is implemented for `&'a str` and `&'a S where S:AsRef<str>`

This gives us control of the lifetimes of the self objects (`'a`) and strips the lifetime completely from the trait.

The disadvantage of this approach is that we have to pass references to our `count` function even for smart references.

[Playground-Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b6e41cf7dddd5d986812dc2053563c5)

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub trait Atom: Copy + Eq + Ord + Display + Debug {}

impl Atom for char {}

pub trait Atoms<A, I>
where
  I: Iterator<Item = A>,
  A: Atom,
{
  fn atoms(self) -> I;
}

impl<'a> Atoms<char, std::str::Chars<'a>> for &'a str {
  fn atoms(self) -> std::str::Chars<'a> {
    self.chars()
  }
}

impl<'a, S> Atoms<char, std::str::Chars<'a>> for &'a S
where
  S: AsRef<str>,
{
  fn atoms(self) -> std::str::Chars<'a> {
    self.as_ref().chars()
  }
}

pub fn count<I, A, T>(pattern: T, item: A) -> usize
where
  A: Atom,
  I: Iterator<Item = A>,
  T: Atoms<A, I>,
{
  pattern.atoms().filter(|i| *i == item).count()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

  use std::rc::Rc;

  use super::*;

  #[test]
  fn test_example() {
    assert_eq!(count("ababbc", 'a'), 2);

    assert_eq!(count(&"ababbc".to_string(), 'a'), 2);
    assert_eq!(count(&Rc::from("ababbc"), 'a'), 2);
  }
}
```

### Switch to Generic Associated Types (unstable)

- reduce the generic type `Atoms<A,I>` to an type `Atoms<A>` with an generic associated type `I<'a>` (which is instantiable at implementations)
- now the function `count` can refer to the lifetime of `I` like this `fn atoms<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::I<'a>`
- and all implementations just have to define how the want to map the lifetime 'a to their own lifetime (for example to `Chars<'a>`)

In this case we have all lifetime constraints in the trait, the implementation can consider to map this lifetime or ignore it. The trait, the implementation and the call site are concise and do not require references or helper lifetimes.

The disadvantage of this solution is that it is unstable, I do not know whether this means that runtime failures would probably occur or that api could change (or both). You will have to activate `#![feature(generic_associated_types)]` to let it run.

[Playground-Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b339c7631dda27ba5224bff5bcd4dc45)

```rust
use std::{fmt::Display, str::Chars};
use std::{fmt::Debug, rc::Rc};

pub trait Atom: Copy + Eq + Ord + Display + Debug {}

impl Atom for char {}

pub trait Atoms<A>
where
  A: Atom,
{
  type I<'a>: Iterator<Item = A>;

  fn atoms<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::I<'a>;
}

impl Atoms<char> for str
{
  type I<'a> = Chars<'a>;

  fn atoms<'a>(&'a self) -> Chars<'a> {
    self.chars()
  }
}

impl <S> Atoms<char> for S
where
  S: AsRef<str>,
{
  type I<'a> = Chars<'a>;

  fn atoms<'a>(&'a self) -> Chars<'a> {
    self.as_ref().chars()
  }
}

pub fn count<A, S>(pattern: S, item: A) -> usize
where
  A: Atom,
  S: Atoms<A>,
{
  pattern.atoms().filter(|i| *i == item).count()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

  use std::rc::Rc;

  use super::*;

  #[test]
  fn test_example() {
    assert_eq!(count("ababbc", 'a'), 2);
    assert_eq!(count("ababbc".to_string(), 'a'), 2);
    assert_eq!(count(Rc::from("ababbc"), 'a'), 2);
  }
}
```